# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pystan'

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-emr, pystan

`Pystan` has been installed successfully on `EMR` nodes (master, task and core nodes), but I still get this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named **pystan**

I installed pystan using `pip install pystan` through `boostrap_scrtip_actions`.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

I use Python 3.7, `emr 6.3.0`.

Comment: Check for any virtual environment problems.

Comment: have you try pip3 install module?

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG Anything specific should I check? because I checked the logs for daemons, provision node but I didn't find any error

Comment: @HSa Tried it with pip3 and I got the same error

Comment: try `python -m pip install pystan`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the issue, posting the answer here for others.
When installing the `pystan` without specifying the version, it installs the latest version and in the latest version of `pystan`, it uses `stan` as the main module and not `pystan`.
To resolve the issue, specify your version or use `import stan` instead.

Refer to the latest pystan doc https://pypi.org/project/pystan/

Comment: I was facing the same problem, thinking that I had installed pystan in some wrong virtual environment, when all that happened is that the developers renamed it -- and changed a bunch of other things: https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrading.html#upgrading

Comment: Which version should we use since I faced the problem that `pystan_apy` file is not found despite installing `pystan_2.9.1`. This leads me to be unable to install `fbprophet 0.5`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, not sure why the developers did this as 'stan' was also a function in the old pystan module. Guess I'll go rewrite my old scripts ^.^

Comment: The pystan version that allows `import pystan` is < 3.0.0. 
At the date of this writing, the latest pystan version that allows `import pystan` is pystan 2.19.1.1 ( which then allows installing fbprophet 0.7.1)

In other words, do `pip install "pystan<3.0.0"`

Comment: Looks like as of 2/2023 - Pip install pystan does not work anymore.  Tried pip install stan as well.